# Detect duplicates csnames defined via \csdef

Tags: macros, etoolbox

I have a large list of `\csdef` that is used repeatedly. In a separate tex file I am trying to detect any duplicates and running into a problem trying to print out the inital definition and the value that the duplicate is trying to set it to.

The two problem lines in the MWE are commented out and the desired output form the MWE is

```
macro 1: Macro 1 Value
         Macro 3 Value

Number of Duplicates = 1
```

The error I am getting is

> LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
>       Type  H   for immediate help.
>        ...
>
> l.29 \csdef{macro 1}{Macro 3 Value}

### Related Question:

- [Report all duplicate macro names defined by \newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/177230/4301)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\newcounter{NumberOfDuplicates}

\LetLtxMacro{\OldCsdef}{\csdef}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\csdef}{%
    m%    #1 = control sequence name
    O{0}% #2 = number of parameters (UNUSED HERE)
    m%    #3 = value
}{%
    \ifcsdef{#1}{%
        \typeout{ERROR: '#1' defined multiple times.}%
%        #1: \csuse{#1}%       <-- Show Old Definition
%       \par\hphantom{#1: }#3% <-- Show new definition
        \stepcounter{NumberOfDuplicates}%
    }{%
        \OldCsdef{#1}{#3}%
    }%
}%

% ------------------------------ Want to check that there are no duplicate csnames here
\csdef{macro 1}{Macro 1 Value}
\csdef{macro 2}{Macro 2 Value}
\csdef{macro 1}{Macro 3 Value}
%
\begin{document}
\medskip\par
Number of Duplicates = \arabic{NumberOfDuplicates}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am guessing that this must be something very obvious that I am not seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you get the “Missing `\begin{document}`” error: you're trying to typeset something in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\newcounter{NumberOfDuplicates}

\LetLtxMacro{\OldCsdef}{\csdef}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\csdef}{%
  m%    #1 = control sequence name
  O{0}% #2 = number of parameters (UNUSED HERE)
  m%    #3 = value
}{%
  \ifcsdef{#1}{%
    \typeout{ERROR: '#1' defined multiple times.}%
    \xappto\duplicateslist{
      #1: \expandafter\meaning\csname #1\endcsname % <-- Old
      \noexpand\par\noexpand\leavevmode
      \noexpand\hphantom{#1: }\unexpanded{#3}% <-- New
      \noexpand\par
    }%
        \stepcounter{NumberOfDuplicates}%
    }{%
        \OldCsdef{#1}{#3}%
    }%
}%

\AtBeginDocument{{\ttfamily\duplicateslist}}

% ------------------------------ Want to check that there are no duplicate csnames here

\csdef{macro 1}{Macro 1 Value}
\csdef{macro 2}{Macro 2 Value}
\csdef{macro 1}{Macro 3 Value}
%
\begin{document}

\medskip\par
Number of Duplicates = \arabic{NumberOfDuplicates}.
\end{document}
```

[image]