# \csdef{} that reports error if command is already defined

Tags: macros, errors, etoolbox

Is there a version of `\csdef{}{}` that reports an error if the value is already defined? The MWE below compiles fine since no checking for the macro already being defined is done and yields:

[image]

I want to replace the `csdef` such that it reports an error condition similar to what a duplicated `\newcommand` would.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\FooValue}{First Value}
\csdef{FooValue}{Second Value}

\csdef{Some Macro}{First Value}
\csdef{Some Macro}{Second Value}

\begin{document}
  FooValue=\csuse{FooValue}

  Some Macro=\csuse{Some Macro}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like some genius :-) had a similar thought a few years ago: [Detect duplicates csnames defined via \csdef](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/360599/4301), so one could use that to redefine `csdef` but find it hard to belive that a similar macro is not already built in.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is such a macro in `etoolbox`. Its `\cs..def...` macros all mirror what you can do with `\def` and `\def` has no check to see if it overrides anything either.

Here are two possible solutions. One is basically `\csdef` with a test, the other is `\newcommand` with `\csname ...\endcsname` (so `\necommand` does the test).

In the `\csdef` with a test I introduced a `\csdef` to a throwaway macro (`\my@etb@throwaway`), so I wouldn't have to collect and gobble the possible arguments of `\csdef` myself. (Of course that means you shouldn't use (`\my@etb@throwaway` anywhere.)

The following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\FooValue}{First Value}
\csdef{FooValue}{Second Value}

\csdef{Some Macro}{First Value}
\csdef{Some Macro}{Second Value}

\newcommand*{\csdefifundef}[1]{%
  \ifcsundef{#1}
    {\csdef{#1}}
    {\PackageError{etoolbox}
      {Command sequence '#1' already defined}
      {You can only define undefined commands with \string\csdefifundef}%
     \csdef{my@etb@throwaway}}}

\csdefifundef{Some Other Macro}{First Value}
\csdefifundef{Some Other Macro}{Second Value}


\newcommand*{\csnewcommand}[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname #1\endcsname}}

\csnewcommand{Some Other Different Macro}{First Value}
\csnewcommand{Some Other Different Macro}{Second Value}

\begin{document}
  FooValue=\csuse{FooValue}

  Some Macro=\csuse{Some Macro}

  FooValue=\csuse{FooValue}

  Some Other Macro=\csuse{Some Other Macro}

  Some Other Different Macro=\csuse{Some Other Different Macro}
\end{document}
```

throws the errors

```
! Package etoolbox Error: Command sequence 'Some Other Macro' already defined.

See the etoolbox package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.18 \csdefifundef{Some Other Macro}{Second Value}

? 

! LaTeX Error: Command \Some Other Different Macro already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.25 ...{Some Other Different Macro}{Second Value}

?
```

and produces the output

[image: FooValue=Second Value//Some Macro=Second Value//FooValue=Second Value//Some Other Macro=First Value//Some Other Different Macro=First Value]

when we force compilation despite the errors.

Answer (score 2):

The TeXbook explains a nice feature when it comes to defining macros: In the `⟨parameter text⟩` of a macro-definition you can use `#{`-notation for a macro whose last argument will be delimited by a left curly brace `{` which—unlike other argument-delimiters—will be re-inserted as if it had been left in place.

Thus I sometimes use a macro-mechanism `\NameToCs` which processes an argument which is delimited by a left curly brace (`{`) and another argument which is nested in curly braces.

The argument nested in curly braces is taken for the name of a `⟨control sequence token⟩` which is to be constructed via `\csname`..`\endcsname`.

`\NameToCs` works as follows:

```
\NameToCs⟨stuff not in curly braces⟩{NameOfCs}
→
⟨stuff not in curly braces⟩\NameOfCs
```

(If you wish to obtain only the control-sequence-token `\NameOfCs`, then you can leave `⟨stuff not in curly braces⟩` empty: `\NameToCs{NameOfCs} → \NameOfCs`)

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\NameToCs{\long\def\NameToCs#1#{\romannumeral0\innerNameToCs{#1}}}%
\newcommand\innerNameToCs[2]{\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}}%
\makeatother
```

There are various uses for such a macro:

1. `\NameToCs{foo}` → `\foo`
2. `\NameToCs\string{foo}` → `\string\foo`
3. `\NameToCs\meaning{foo}` → `\meaning\foo`
4. `\NameToCs\global\long\def{foo}...` → `\global\long\def\foo...`
5. `\NameToCs\newcommand*{foo}...` → `\newcommand*\foo...`
6. `\NameToCs\NameToCs\global\let{foo}={bar}` → `\NameToCs\global\let\foo={bar}`  → `\global\let\foo=\bar`

Usage-example 5 can be applied within the `⟨balanced text⟩` of the definition of a macro `\csnewcommand`:

```
\newcommand*\csnewcommand{\NameToCs\newcommand}%
```

Putting the pieces together in a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Define the macro \NameToCs:
\makeatletter
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\NameToCs{\long\def\NameToCs#1#{\romannumeral0\innerNameToCs{#1}}}%
\newcommand\innerNameToCs[2]{\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}}%
\makeatother

% Define \csnewcommand and \csrenewcommand and \csProvideCommand and \csDeclareRobustCommand
\newcommand*\csnewcommand{\NameToCs\newcommand}%
\newcommand*\csrenewcommand{\NameToCs\renewcommand}%
\newcommand*\csProvideCommand{\NameToCs\ProvideCommand}%
\newcommand*\csDeclareRobustCommand{\NameToCs\DeclareRobustCommand}%

\csnewcommand*{FooValue}{FooValue's First Value}
% This throws an error:
%\csnewcommand*{FooValue}{FooValue's Second Value}
% This does not throw an error.
%\csrenewcommand*{FooValue}{FooValue's Second Value}

\csnewcommand*{Some Macro}{Some Macro's First Value}
% This throws an error:
%\csnewcommand*{Some Macro}{Some Macro's Second Value}
% This does not throw an error.
%\csrenewcommand*{Some Macro}{Some Macro's Second Value}

\csnewcommand*{Some Other Macro}{Some Other Macro's First Value}
% This throws an error:
%\csnewcommand*{Some Other Macro}{Some Other Macro's Second Value}
% This does not throw an error.
\csrenewcommand*{Some Other Macro}{Some Other Macro's Second Value}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\texttt{\NameToCs\string{FooValue}} is defined as \texttt{\NameToCs\meaning{FooValue}}\\
Expanding \texttt{\NameToCs\string{FooValue}} yields: \NameToCs{FooValue}

\bigskip

\noindent
\texttt{\NameToCs\string{Some Macro}} is defined as \texttt{\NameToCs\meaning{Some Macro}}\\
Expanding \texttt{\NameToCs\string{Some Macro}} yields: \NameToCs{Some Macro}

\bigskip

\noindent
\texttt{\NameToCs\string{Some Other Macro}} is defined as \texttt{\NameToCs\meaning{Some Other Macro}}\\
Expanding \texttt{\NameToCs\string{Some Other Macro}} yields: \NameToCs{Some Other Macro}

\end{document}
```

[image]